# Is Age a demographic?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, terminology

Good Day,

I was playing a game with my friends and an argument arose as to whether "Age is a demographic". I think this is incorrect in the sense of both grammar and terminology use...As I said age isn't an example of a demographic BUT it is an example of a demographic **attribute/property/characteristic/**....(I later learned the correct term is demographic factor)..Am I wrong to say this?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. *Demographic* has a [noun meaning](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/demographic_2) as well as an adjective meaning. While age itself is a personal attribute, all people of a certain age or age range would certainly constitute *a demographic* in the noun sense. Is this the crux of your question, or something else?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with, for example, [*a demographic such as age will be of little value if the age profiles of users and non-users are identical.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+demographic+such+as+age%22) Arguing that it should be *a demographic **factor*** or ***metric*** is just anal nit-picking. Consequently, I think this question is effectively a peeve.

Answer (score -1):

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demographic) says that *demographic* can be either an adjective or a noun:

> [Adjective] relating to the structure of populations:
>   *the demographic trend is toward an older population.*
>
> [Noun] a particular sector of a population:
>   *the drink is popular with a young demographic.*

As you can see, it *is* grammatical to use it as either a noun or adjective, and age is indeed considered a demographic.

Etymologically (according to [a different Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/)) the adjective came first, derived from the word *demography*. *Demographic*, as a noun, has been around for a while (~1972) and while originally American, has spread across the globe.

Comment: I don't think it's directly relevant that a dictionary licenses ***demographic*** used as a noun (to refer to *a particular sector* of a population), since OP is asking about its use with a completely different referent (the *metric* used to identify that class of people, not the people themselves).